# Mixing QtQuickControls 1 and 2

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I am developing a QML Desktop application. The menu-bar in QtQuick 2 cannot have keyboard shortcuts. The ApplicationWindow in QtQuickControls 1 does not have a palette option, to set e.g. the highlight of the style.

Is it possible to use Qt Quick Controls 1 and 2 in the same file?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can mix them in most cases, though I don't think that it's possible to use e.g. `MenuItem` from Controls 1 in `Menu` from Controls 2, and vice versa.

However, as of Qt 5.10, `MenuItem` from Qt Quick Controls 2 has support for [actions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#action-prop), through which you can assign a shortcut.

[This page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html) has more information on the differences between the two modules.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Import one, or both with a local namespace qualifier.

```
// controls without qualifier will be Qt Quick Controls 2 elements
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as QQC1

QQC1.ApplicationWindow {
    statusBar: QQC1.StatusBar {
        RowLayout {
            Label { text: "I'm a QQC2 element!" }
        }
        Slider { from: 2; to: 36; value: 11 }
    }
}
```